# ejdb Java binding not working "no jejdb in java.library.path"

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ejdb

I'm trying to get the java binding of ejdb (http://ejdb.org/) to work.
The bindings can be found on Github: https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb-java

The binding can be build via the usual `./configure && make && make install` step. The result is a libjejdb.so file in the target directory and a java library.

Running the examples fails:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/Users/foo/test/lib -jar jejdb-sample1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jejdb in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at org.ejdb.driver.EJDB.<clinit>(EJDB.java:56)
at org.ejdb.sample1.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

I checked the supplied java.library.path and it does contain libjejdb.so.

After that I created a multiple copies named jejdb.som jejdb, and so on, just to be sure:

```
~/test/lib % file *
jejdb:             Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
jejdb.so:          Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libjejdb.so:       Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libjejdb.so.1:     Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libjejdb.so.1.0.0: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I still get the same error...

The library in the code is loaded via

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jejdb");
}
```

and I would expect that libjejdb.so is the correct filename.

I'm confused that the library is still not found?

Comment: I also did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that you where able to build the code in the first place because on my side I needed to change stuff in configure, configure.ac and Makefile.in to be able for this to compile properly on MacOSX

However, assuming that this is not a real issue, I did the following to get the example to run and assuming that your .so file is installed in ~/test/lib as mentioned above

```
# remove un-needed environment variable
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# set proper shared library names on MacOSX in 
for n in libjejdb.dylib libjejdb.1.dylib libjejdb.1.0.0.dylib; do ln -s libjejdb.so ~/test/lib/$n; done
# Relaunch example using your previous command
java -Djava.library.path=/Users/foo/test/lib -jar jejdb-sample1.jar
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!
I forget that I changed the ./configure script to use darwin of the SDK to get it to work. I wasn't aware that on macosx the shared library names are also handled a little bit different :-)